# WebClient.DownloadFile convert to File VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, webclient

Does anyone know how to parse a Webclient.DowloadFile to File in VB.Net?
I'm currently using the following Code but I keep getting the errors: 
(BC30491) Expression does not produce a value. 
(BC30311) Value of Type can not be converted to File

```
Private Function DepartmentDataDownloader() As String
    Dim webClient As New System.Net.WebClient
    'I get here the error BC30491
    Dim result As File = webClient.DownloadFile("https://intern.hethoutsemeer.nl/index2.php?option=com_webservices&controller=csv&method=hours.board.fetch&key=F2mKaXYGzbjMA4V&element=departments", "intern.hethoutsemeer.nl.1505213278-Departments.csv")

    If webClient IsNot Nothing Then
        'and here BC30311
        Dim result As File = webClient
        UploaderFromDownload(webClient)
    End If
    Return ""
End Function
```

Comment: The func [`DownloadFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez801hhe(v=vs.110).aspx) will not return value.  And you can init `File` with the path you store the downloaded file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`DownloadFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144194(v=vs.110).aspx) method doesn't return a value, because `DownloadFile` is a `Sub`. This is the reason why you get the [`BC30491`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/error-messages/expression-does-not-produce-a-value) error. The second parameter specifies the path of the local file (and the result of the download).

So you can try something like the following:

```
Dim webClient As New System.Net.WebClient

'after this the file specified on second parameter should exists.
webClient.DownloadFile("https://intern.hethoutsemeer.nl/index2.php?option=com_webservices&controller=csv&method=hours.board.fetch&key=F2mKaXYGzbjMA4V&element=departments", "intern.hethoutsemeer.nl.1505213278-Departments.csv")

If webClient IsNot Nothing Then

    'do something with the downloaded file (File.OpenRead(), File.*).
    'Dim result As File
    UploaderFromDownload(webClient)
End If
```

You also try to assign the `WebClient` value to a `File` variable. This is not possible so you get the [`BC30311`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/misc/bc30311) error.

> **Hint:** You can't create an instance of the `File` class. The `File` class provides static methods for the creation, copying, deletion, moving, and opening of a single file, and aids in the creation of `FileStream` objects.
>   **source:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file